# issue on deploying edX server on the internet

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, edx, openedx

Aim: Get open edX running on my self-host server and general public can access it.

What I have done:
I have successfully run the vagrant box in window7, following by instructions, and everything run in localhost.

Instructions：

http://open-edx-windows-7-installation-instructions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/1_Introduction.html

I can get my edx system to run on

LMS - 192.168.33.10

CMS(studio) - 192.168.33.10:18010.

Now, I'll need public ip with above ports so that general public can access my lms & cms which runs in my vagrant machine.

What should I do?

Comment: You might try using the Bitnami community AMI, it has open edX already installed for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want other user access the localhost you can use secure tunnel on the localhost using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

It's simple you just download the ngrok package, for example in OS X

1. `$ wget https://dl.ngrok.com/ngrok_2.0.19_darwin_amd64.zip`
2. `$ unzip /path/to/ngrok_2.0.19_darwin_amd64.zip`
3. Run `$ ngrok -help` for documentation.